# add title to front page teaser news feed

Tags: blocks, theming, nodes

I would like to add a title to my news feed. I have tried to edit node--teaser.tpl.php and added

```
<?php if($page['feed-title']): ?>
<!-- start feed title -->
<?php print render($page['feed-title']); ?>
<!-- end feed title -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

on top, then I added

```
regions[feed-title] = Feed Title
```

in my theme.info file. I created a block which is assigned to this region but still, nothing is being displayed, why not? Am I doing something wrong or can I not add regions into a region template file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!templates!page.tpl.php/7) template file used by the Bartik module, you will notice it uses code like the following to render a region.

```
  <?php if ($page['triptych_first'] || $page['triptych_middle'] || $page['triptych_last']): ?>
    <div id="triptych-wrapper"><div id="triptych" class="clearfix">
      <?php print render($page['triptych_first']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['triptych_middle']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['triptych_last']); ?>
    </div></div> <!-- /#triptych, /#triptych-wrapper -->
  <?php endif; ?>
```

node--teaser.tpl.php is not used to render a page, but a node into a page. It is hierarchic, someway: html.tpl.php wraps the content of page.tpl.php, which wraps the content of node.tpl.php.
Regions are part of a page, not a node; therefore, the template file where to render the regions is page.tpl.php or any suggested templates used instead of that one.

Answer (score -1):

When you add a region in theme.info file, you have to render the region in `page.tpl.php`.

That's where you are doing wrong. You are doing it in `node.tpl.php`.

Don't forget to clear the cache after you render your region in `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: Can somebody explain the reason of negative vote here ?